# What would have happened if Amandil hadn't tried to sail to Valinor?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Amandil, a few years before the Invasion of Valinor, sneaked off the island with three of his most trusted men and attempted to sail to Valinor to ask pardon and forgiveness for Númenor. He was never heard from again, though it is possible that the Valar heeded his plea considering the faithful were spared and their ships were pushed to safety from the Destruction of Númenor.

Would the Valar have spared the faithful if Amandil had not attempted to sail to Valinor and beg them for forgiveness?

Answer (score 2):

If you recall, the faithful led by Elendil and his sons, Isildur and Anarion *were* spared from death on the day of the downfall of the Land of the Star. Westernesse itself was not spared after its king and so many of its people fell back into the worship of evil. But the Faithful mounted their ships and the "consuming wave" carried them "like birds of the storm" to Middle-earth, where they established the kingdoms of Gondor and Arnor in exile.

It's not known in the story if Amandil ever reached the Blessed Realm but  Tolkien suggests that Elendil and his followers, The Faithful, may have been spared from the destruction of Númenor because of Amandil's mission to Valinor.

Comment: well Tolkien always left his books with little cliffhangers leaving us wondering, but in my opinion i just assume Amandil made it to Valinor by blessing of Ulmo and made his prayer to Manwe, then by the time of the Downfall the Valar forewarned Elendil and his sons and people to wait for the signal of the west that Amandil told Elendil about. but thats just me and my conclusion

Comment: Welcome to the site, Marcus! "was not spared because it could not be spared" could probably be more simply written as "was not spared because." You can edit your post (if you like my suggestion) by clicking the "edit" link at the lower left of your answer.